# Castle Windsor proxies, implicit interfaces and WPF Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle-dynamicproxy

I am attempting to implement a WPF ViewModel using Castle Windsor Dynamic Proxies.  The idea is that I want to supply an interface (IPerson below should suffice as an example), a concrete backing class, and an interceptor (for providing automatic implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged).  The interceptor implementation is here: http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/Best-Implementation-Of-INotifyPropertyChange-Ever

The problem that I am seeing is that when I bind my models to WPF controls, the controls don't see the models as implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.  I believe (but am not sure) that this is because Windsor is implementing the interfaces explicitly, and WPF seems to expect them to be implicit.

Is there any way to make this work, so that changes to the model are caught by the interceptor and raised to the model?

All versions of the libraries are the latest: Castle.Core 2.5.1.0 and Windsor 2.5.1.0

Code is as follows:

```
// My model's interface
public interface IPerson : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string First { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}

// My concrete class:
[Interceptor(typeof(NotifyPropertyChangedInterceptor))]
class Person : IPerson
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (s,e)=> { };
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}

// My windsor installer
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<NotifyPropertyChangedInterceptor>()
            .ImplementedBy<NotifyPropertyChangedInterceptor>()
            .LifeStyle.Transient);
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IPerson, INotifyPropertyChanged>()
            .ImplementedBy<Person>().LifeStyle.Transient);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer turned out to be fairly straightforward...  The code from http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/Best-Implementation-Of-INotifyPropertyChange-Ever defines the interceptor as:

```
public class NotifyPropertyChangedInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler _subscribers = delegate { };

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged))
        {
            HandleSubscription(invocation);
            return;
        }

        invocation.Proceed();

        if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("set_"))
        {
            FireNotificationChanged(invocation);
        }
    }

    private void HandleSubscription(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var handler = (PropertyChangedEventHandler)invocation.Arguments[0];

        if (invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("add_"))
        {
            _subscribers += handler;
        }
        else
        {
            _subscribers -= handler;
        }
    }

    private void FireNotificationChanged(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var propertyName = invocation.Method.Name.Substring(4);
        _subscribers(invocation.InvocationTarget, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In my case, the InvocationTarget was simply not the right entity to be passing as the first argument to PropertyChanged (because I am generating a proxy).  Changing the last function to the following fixed the problem:

```
private void FireNotificationChanged(IInvocation invocation)
{
    var propertyName = invocation.Method.Name.Substring(4);
    _subscribers(invocation.Proxy, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the members of your Class that implements the interface Virtual.